# Top 10 Index - Match Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel

I try to create a top 10 list of products that have a coverage over a year ranked by inventory value. Using index match to map against the inventory value i ran into 2 problems.

Here's the formula i use (in that case to return the item no):

> =INDEX(ITEM;MATCH(LARGE(IF((COVERAGE>365)(COVERAGE<9999)(CATEGORY="Bike");INVENTORY;);COUNTA(G$64:G64));INVENTORY;0))

The large formula returns the nth inventory value for products where coverage exceeds 365 days, is less than 9999 (default value in case we don't have a sales projection) and falls into category "Bike".

That works so far as intended, however in case the inventory value isn't unique, looking up the row via the match function gives me the first entry, not the one that's in line with the large if criteria (so it can return a product from another category).

On top if there are less than 10 items to begin with, the large if returns a value of 0 and the index match then fills in the remaining rows out of the Top 10 with the first entries that report 0 value regardless of the if criteria.

Comment: Use AGGREGATE with COUNTIF as the  *k* argument.

Comment: Do a search on here - this has been asked and answered.